# Nav.Link trigger Router

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap

[simple example of how to use react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

Know with react-bootstrap Nav.Link using bootstrap [Navbar](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/navbar/) (Color schemes) made the changes below for the simple example but the Route doesn't work anymore. Is it suppose to Programmatically detect the click and redirect to the correct page/component or by the click the Router should detect the correct path if so how what is need to change to work?

```
function Header() {
    return(
        <NavbarMenu />
    )
 /* 
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/weather">Weather</Link>
      </li>      
    </ul>
  );
  */
}

class NavbarMenu extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <Navbar fixed="top" bg="dark" variant="dark">
                <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                  <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link href="#about">About</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link href="#topics">Topics</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link href="#weather">Weather</Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
                <Form inline>
                  <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
                  <Button variant="outline-info">Search</Button>
                </Form>
            </Navbar>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well went with the option of [Use composition and render a Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router) that is Programmatically... but still think that Nav.Link must be using Link underline so there must be a way for it to trigger the route.

```
class NavbarMenu extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <Navbar fixed="top" bg="dark" variant="dark">
                <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                  <Link to="/weather">Weather Link</Link>
                  <Route render={({ history}) => (<Nav.Link onClick={() => { history.push('/home') }}>Home</Nav.Link>)} />
                  <Route render={({ history}) => (<Nav.Link onClick={() => { history.push('/about') }}>About</Nav.Link>)} />
                  <Route render={({ history}) => (<Nav.Link onClick={() => { history.push('/topics') }}>Topics</Nav.Link>)} />
                  <Route render={({ history}) => (<Nav.Link onClick={() => { history.push('/weather') }}>Weather</Nav.Link>)} />
                </Nav>
                <Form inline>
                  <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
                  <Button variant="outline-info">Search</Button>
                </Form>
            </Navbar>
        )
    }
}
```